# which class name is used for creating batch contacts in google people api

Tags: php, google-people-api

```
$person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person($create_data[0]);
$exe = $service->people->createContact($person);*/
```

This has been used to create a single contact.Which class is used for batch to create a contact ?

Answer (score 0):

### The documentation explains how to [perform batching requests for the People API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/batch)

There is no "implemented batch class" as such, instead you need to perform an HTTP request to the batch endpoint URL.

See also the following posts:

- [Batch request to People API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364960/batch-update-contacts-google-people-api) example.
- [GET request (with cURL) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032643/php-get-request-sending-headers)
- [Google_Http_Batch in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840333/google-calendar-api-batch-request-php)